# How To Create a Resolution Scalable Arrow For Website

Tags: html, css, image, svg, utf-8

I have seen in Yahoo and other sites including sites for mobile where they have this little arrows pointing up and down and these seem to scale when one zooms into the viewport. They seem crisp on every resolution level as well and I am looking to create something similar. Here is the arrow I am talking about:

[arrow image >](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/58951757/arrow_down.jpg)

This arrow is from the yahoo "Download All" button. Was it done with SVG, is it a UTF-8 symbol? Can this be done in CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like Font Awesome.

http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/

Font Awesome is for use with Bootstrap but there are many similar fonts ets out there for regular use too.

Here's an article detailing some:

http://thenextweb.com/dd/2012/10/12/7-gorgeous-icon-fonts-to-speed-up-your-site-and-your-design-process/

These icon sets are usually scaleable vector icons meaning they will work well at different resolutions.

Comment: Perfect, thank you! Font Awesome provides me a lots of icons, scalable too!

Comment: Any idea how these are made?

Comment: Not totally sure @polymorph. Black Magic of some sort I assume.

Comment: Actually I just found out. The icons are made in vector graphics, more specifically SVG. These icons are exported to several tools online which can convert these icon into web fonts. These fonts are then handled by using CSS and applying font specific formatting such as font-size etc. They are availble in IE8+